# ReactJS app (website) strange text autoreplacement on Android devices (Chrome) for SOME users

Tags: android, reactjs

Some of our users (4-5 from 150 now) experience very strange issues that I can't represent and can't even imagine. We have reactjs app (website) with recipes, that are just regular HTML pages loaded from rest api and displayed as frontent react app.

The issue is that some words in this texts for only SOME users replaced to incorrect, not existing words (they looks like AI made words, they similar to real words, but not exist in real life). I googled everything and dont see something close to this problem.
All this users have Android devices (Samsung, Redmi, etc) and Google chrome mobile browser. For me on Redmi with Google Chrome all works fine.

Any tips or how this is possible at all? I have no clue.

If this matter - texts is on Russian (I even start thinking about some conspiracy theory that some VPN/providers/proxy/routers/browser/android firmware replace russian words received from API because of sanctions...) I have no other explanation.